# On Biblical Verses Invoked in Papal Encyclicals or Ecumenical Councils

Tags: catholicism, bible, papacy, ecumenical-council, encyclicals

Is there an expedient way to find out if a given some particular biblical verse, it has been invoked in either a papal encyclical or a document of an ecumenical council without having to retrieve that document and read through it? For example, if I wanted to know if 2 Pet. 3:16 has been quoted such, is there some papal data center that I may access in order to see where may have been quoted?

If not, is there some way to do the same for the more general book and chapter; say, 2 Pet. 3 in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On Biblical Verses Invoked in Papal Encyclicals or Ecumenical Councils**

There exist no concordance for papal encyclicals or Ecumenical Councils. One simply has to read a them as they are and the footnotes that follow the particular section one is reading. Strange that no one has thought to do this; but I do understand that most who read these things in their entirety are priests, religious and educators of Catholicism in universities and/or seminaries. The average Catholic rarely reads such documents in question. Thus a concordance is not really valuable as a tool.

Thus as an example, take the Apostolic Constitution of [Munificentissimus Deus](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_p-xii_apc_19501101_munificentissimus-deus.html) defining the Dogma of the Assumption all the quotes Biblical or otherwise are found at the end under the title of endnotes! This is the traditional manner of both papal decrees and ecumenical councils. The Church sees no need to have a concordance of these documents at the present moment in time.

If you are looking to find a particular biblical quotations, it would be best to know under what circumstances the Church would likely employ a certain passage(s) of Scripture. Not always an easy thing to do!

Comment: "_There exist no concordance for_ […] _Ecumenical Councils_" What about [Mansi](http://patristica.net/mansi)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this site for Ecumenical Council references.

https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf214.html

Just enter the book, chapter, and verse.